# Pulling code from GIT repository other than clone command

Tags: git, github, tfs

I am trying to pull code from GIT repository other than clone command. Is there any other way or process where I can directly pass the credentials to command and pull the code to local repositiry from TFS?

Something like init.

Comment: You're looking fro the clone command. What about the clone command isn't working for you? You should be able to pass the credentials on the Uri like so: `git clone https://username:password@mygithost.com/my/repository` or use the Git Credential Manager on Windows https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which you want to get from remote repository.

When working with other people's repositories, there are a few basic Git commands to remember:

```
git clone
git fetch
git merge
git pull
```

If you want to grab a complete copy of another user's repository, you may have to use `git clone` or `git fetch` command like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
# Clones a repository to your computer
```

However both of these command need to pass the credentials  of the remote repository.

If you just want to merge different people's work together with yours you can use `git merge` command. And `pull` is a combination of fetch and merge.

You can go in-depth on these commands with the [help link](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/) from GitHub.